# Custom colors for TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes, material-design-in-xaml

Working with Material Design in XAML, I first used the default colors.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="DeepOrange" SecondaryColor="Amber" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

After that, I wanted to use custom colors, and followed their wiki for [Custom Colors](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit//wiki/Custom-Palette-Hues) and updated to the following:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueLightBrush" Color="#92c9a6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueMidBrush" Color="#1C8875"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueDarkBrush" Color="#0b4d49"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <!-- accent -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="#6F91B2"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#104F7A"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="#0D3351"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This changes the color of the application, except for the inactive `TabItem`s in the `TabControl`. The header of the inactive `TabItem`s disappears.

With the default colors it looks like this:
[image: Theme with standard colors.]

When changing to the custom colors, the header text of the inactive `TabItem` "Scan History" disappears.

[image: Theme with custom colors.]

Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

**Update**

The XAML of the `TabControl` itself:

```
<TabControl Name="AppTabs" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <TabItem Header="Scan Configuration">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Scan History">
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Could you please post your `TabControl`? I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Updated the post with the Xaml of the `TabControl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MaterialDesign themes have a notion of a *base theme*, a *primary* and a *secondary* color, where the base theme specifies whether it is a light or dark theme. When using the `BundledTheme`, you have to specify all three parameters, like you did in your first example, otherwise the theme is incomplete and will not be applied. Hence, this line in your custom approach will not pull in any theme resources.

```
<materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" />
```

If you would create a *complete* theme resource dictionary with *all* colors that are used by the MaterialDesign styles and templates, then you would not need this line anyway. However, you only override a *subset* of all colors, the others are undefined, since there are no other (fallback) theme resource.

You have two options to solve the issue:

- Pull in a fallback theme that applies all other colors that you did not override by specifying the *base theme* **and** both *primary* and *secondary* colors in the `BundledTheme`.

  ```
  <Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="DeepOrange" SecondaryColor="Amber" />
           <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueLightBrush" Color="#92c9a6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueMidBrush" Color="#1C8875"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueDarkBrush" Color="#0b4d49"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <!-- accent -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="#6F91B2"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#104F7A"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="#0D3351"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
     </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
  ```
- Define *all* colors that are used by the styles and templates. In your specific case, the inactive brush is `MaterialDesignBody`, but of course there are many more colours that need to be defined, especially if you are using other controls as well.

  ```
  <Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignBody" Color="#FF00FF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueLightBrush" Color="#92c9a6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueMidBrush" Color="#1C8875"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueDarkBrush" Color="#0b4d49"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <!-- accent -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="#6F91B2"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#104F7A"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="#0D3351"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>

        <!-- Many, many more brushes... -->
     </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
  ```

For `TabControl` you can find the used brushes in its styles and templates [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/6cb2515640b74d139072284c880c844a35b3e9f8/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TabControl.xaml).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, ended up using the first option that uses the fallback theme and that works.